# Python regex and replace with incremented number

Tags: python, regex

I have a file which contains in it several lines of problematic syntax, I'd like to do find all occurrences of it and replace it with acceptable syntax.

Example:

```
<field id="someId" type="xs:decimal" bind="someId">
    <description/>
    <region id="Calc.R_315.`0" page="1"/>
    <region id="Calc.R_315.`1" page="1"/>
</field>
```

I'd like to a string replacement of all occurrences of

```
<dot><tick><number> i.e. .`0 or .`1 or .`2 et cetera
```

with

```
<dash><number> i.e. -1 or -2 or -3
```

Notice it begins at 1 instead of 0.

I have the following python code which performs an inline replacement of however it starts at 0, I'd like it to start at 1.

```
with fileinput.input(files="file.xml", inplace=True, backup='.original.bak', mode='r') as f:
    for line in f:
        pattern = "\.`(\d+)"
        result = re.sub(pattern, lambda exp: "-{}".format(exp.groups()[0]), line)
        print(result, end='')
```

How to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Why doesn't adding 1 to the argument in the `format()` function work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
s = """
<field id="someId" type="xs:decimal" bind="someId">
   <description/>
   <region id="Calc.R_315.`0" page="1"/>
   <region id="Calc.R_315.`1" page="1"/>
</field>
"""
new_s = re.sub('\.`\d+', '{}', s).format(*map(lambda x:'-{}'.format(int(x)+1), re.findall('(?<=\.`)\d+(?=")', s)))
print(new_s)
```

Output:

```
<field id="someId" type="xs:decimal" bind="someId">
  <description/>
  <region id="Calc.R_315-1" page="1"/>
  <region id="Calc.R_315-2" page="1"/>
</field>
```

Answer (score 8):

You are almost at the solution yourself!

The only thing remaining is to convert the captured number into an `int`, and add 1 to it. Simple!

So the relevant line of code becomes:

```
result = re.sub(pattern, lambda exp: "-{}".format(int(exp.groups()[0]) + 1), line)
```

Another slight modification that can be made is to change `.groups()[0]` to `.group(1)`. You can learn more about `group` and its usage in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group).

One last thing: It is always better to define your regex pattern as a raw string so as to avoid any future headaches.